# Do pictures and videos sent via the Facebook Messenger Android app expire?

Tags: photos, video, facebook-messenger

I sent a few pictures and videos to a friend via the Facebook Messenger Android app.  Do pictures and videos sent via Facebook Messenger Android app expire? I.e., will they disappear or will only a thumbnail will be available after a while? E.g., in the Line Android app, only a thumbnail will be available after a while.

I did not set a [timer](https://www.facebook.com/help/messenger-app/1039542879410863?cms_platform=android-app&helpref=platform_switcher) to have everyone's messages disappear from the chat.